# Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587 in android

Tags: java, android, email, smtp

gave so many trails to send an attachment over mail but getting this error "javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
nested exception is: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host unreachable"

Not getting what went wrong please find the below coding details

On button click calling the JavaMailAPI and passing the mailing details f=of both sender the receiver

JavaMailAPI.java

```
    public class JavaMailAPI extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;
    private Multipart _multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    static {
        Security.addProvider(new com.example.sendmail.JSSEProvider());
    }
    public JavaMailAPI(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }
    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body,
                                      String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(
                    body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(body);
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            // Put parts in message
            message.setContent(_multipart);
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName("download image");
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }
    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;
        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }
        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }
        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }
        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }
    }
```

JSSEProvider.java

```
 public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {
    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController
                .doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
                    public Void run() {
                        put("SSLContext.TLS",
                                "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                        put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                        put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                            

"org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                        put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                                "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                        return null;
                    }
                });
    }
    }
```

Add added the below jars in gradle

```
implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
implementation files('libs/additionnal.jar')
implementation files('libs/mail.jar')
```

And added Internet permission in manifest

Not getting what went wrong, please help me out to get it solved. Thank u

Comment: Is it only when you try to send an attachment?

Comment: @blackapps even unable to send a simple mail too. Thank u